# The minimal number of permutation matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations

What is the minimal number of permutation matrices we need to fix in order to express any other permutation matrix as a product of those fixed matrices (actually, we can take every matrix of those fixed matrices several times).

Comment: You can do this with just two if you pick them correctly (and of course fix the sizes of the matrices).

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I was thinking about that. For example, if we fix the size to be n. Can you please explain a little bit more?

Comment: This is a lot easier to deal with in terms of actual permutations rather than permutation matrices (since this is the same thing, but easier to write). Consider the one corresponding to swapping the first two elements, and the one corresponding to adding $1$ (mod $n$).

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft So, to prove that rigorously I need to construct bijection between the permutations and permutation matrices and then say that every permutation can be expressed through cycle of length n and a transposition?

Comment: That would at least make everything a lot easier to write down (note that the bijection is quite simple to describe).

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft thank you very much! You helped a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the permutations of $n$ elements can be generated by these two permutations (I use [cycle notation](http://mathcircle.berkeley.edu/BMC3/perm/node3.html) for readablility): the transposition $s = (1,2)$ and the cycle $r = (1,2,\ldots, n-1,n)$. First of all I suppose known already that each permutation is the composition of transpositions (also called exchanges or 2-cycles) $(a_i, a_j)$. The first step is to construct the $n$ transpositions of the form $(i, {i+1})$ and $(1,n)$ with $1 \leq i < n$. One can easily verify that they are obtained as $r^{-j} \circ s \circ r^j$ with $0 \leq j < n$. The next step is to generate the remaining transpositions $(i,j)$. These can be obtained by the "palindromic" compositions:  $(i, i+1) \circ (i+1, i+2) \circ \ldots \circ (j-2, j-1) \circ (j-1,j) \circ (j-2, j-1) \circ \ldots \circ (i+1, i+2) \circ (i, i+1) $ This proves that every permutation can be written as a word using only $r$ and $s$. Note that this construction is only of theorethical importance. In practice, if one wants to construct groups generated by some permutations it is more practical to use algorithms like the [Schreier-Sims algorithm](http://www.math.rwth-aachen.de/~Graduiertenkolleg/schools/2011/slides/slides_ss11_niemeyer_2.pdf).